# How to convert JSON column to list in R

Tags: json, r, apply

I have data set like this

```html
genres
[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]
[{"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 28, "name": "Action"}]
[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}]
[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}, {"id": 18, "name": "Drama"}, {"id": 53, "name": "Thriller"}]
[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]
[{"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}]
[{"id": 16, "name": "Animation"}, {"id": 10751, "name": "Family"}]
```

Now I want to populate a drop down list of Shiny application so I want to convert the column JSON to data table, I use apply functions but does not get desired result, can someone please help me out.

**Code:**

```
lapply(dt, fromJSON(dt$genres))
```

Comment: what does _your apply function_ look like?

Comment: can you please share your code ?

Comment: fromJSON(dt$genres[1]) gives result for one column but I want to do the same for all column then it will not give desired result 

lapply(dt, fromJSON(dt$genres))

Answer (score 0):

I am new to R so it may be not best solution but here my finding which is working in my case, please let me know if any feedback

```
 genre <- raw$genres
 genreList <- lapply(genre,function(x) fromJSON(x))
 genreList <- genreList[sapply(genreList, function(x) as.numeric(dim(x)[1])) > 0]
 genreList <- genreList[!sapply(genreList, is.null)]
 finalGenre <- unique(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), genreList))
```

And the output

```
      id            name
1     28          Action
2     53        Thriller
3  10769         Foreign
4     12       Adventure
5  10751          Family
6    878 Science Fiction
7     27          Horror
8     16       Animation
9     80           Crime
10    35          Comedy
11 10770        TV Movie
12    18           Drama
13    99     Documentary
14 10752             War
15 10402           Music
16 10749         Romance
17    14         Fantasy
18    37         Western
19    36         History
20  9648         Mystery
```